# Yocto CI Build number ? PR Service do not increment ${PR}

Tags: version, yocto, fido

I'm trying to use the PR Service of Yocto (`fido`) but each time I launch bitbake on my recipe the package get the `${PR}=r0`.

**local.conf**

```
INHERIT += "buildhistory"
BUILDHISTORY_COMMIT = "1"
PRSERV_HOST = "localhost:0"
```

**recipe.bb**

```
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
BPV = "1.1.0"
PV = "${BPV}+gitr${SRCPV}"  # I know, I should use a tag instead.
SRC_BRANCH = "master"
SRC_URI = "xxx.git;protocol=ssh;branch=${SRC_BRANCH}"
```

This produce a package with the name `xxx_1.1.0+gitrAUTOINC+e7de1c757a-r0.0`.

I was expecting to get

- Build #1

  - `xxx_1.1.0+gitr0+e7de1c757a-r0.0`
- Build #2

  - `xxx_1.1.0+gitr1+e7de1c757a-r1.0`
- And so on...

I want to use the PR as the build number. Getting something like `"1.1.0.453`
Where "**major**.**minor**.**revision**.**build-number**"

I see two problems here:

1. The PR is not incremented, even if I change the recipe or the project source code.
2. The name of the package is not the one I'm expecting. Why there is a "r0" before the `git` and why revision is "r0.0" instead of "r0" ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

It's not expected to increment PR, it increments on EXTENDPRAUTO (which is used in PKGR after PR).

And it's also used in SRCPV to get always increasing number in front of the git hash (everytime the hash is changed to something PRSERV haven't seen for this recipe before it will return max+1).

And you shouldn't use tags in SRCREV, because bitbake will always run git ls-remote against the remote git repository to convert tag names to git sha (which breaks when you cannot connect to the git repository e.g. when disconnected from VPN and also significantly slows down the parsing of the recipes).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've read your answer and then I read more information on https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/PR_Service, but I'm still mixed up about PR not incremented. Is it normal that the package name contains the string `AUTOINC+` ? If I need a build number (like in CI/DI), is PR + PR Service is the right way ? Else, do you see something else wrong in my recipe ?

Comment: The revision is 0.0 as the added part is the number from the PR service. You should see it change 0.0 to 0.1 so its the PR value from the recipe + "." + X where X is the PR service value.

Comment: @RichardPurdie: Thank you it's clearer. So the PR service is not what I'm looking for to handle a build number. Do you have an idea on how to implement a kind of build number that increment for **EACH** build being part of the package's name ?

Comment: I think it will do what you want, you just have to understand its the part after the "." in the package release field.

Comment: @RichardPurdie, I'm not sure to understand what you said, if I understand well the PR service will only update the value of z in "xxx_1.1.0+gitr1+e7de1c757a-r1.z" and **only** when the recipe content **get changed**. What I'm looking is more about an automatic build number (_integer_) that get increase **AT EACH build** even if the recipe content or code source of package has not changed.

Comment: **nayfe** on the IRC Yocto channel proposed me to read more about [image-buildinfo](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/image-buildinfo.bbclass). From what I've understand we can use it for a build number in (CI) environment.

Comment: Image-buildinfo is related to image, not packages, so not relevent for your need. You can do something like MY_BUILD_VERSION=$vvv bitbake <image> and set PV to MY_BUILD_VERSION, sort off. But I don't understand why you want to bump versions when nothing changes, it's quite strange ;)